# Angular multiple lazyloaded routes/paths using the one module

Tags: angular

I'm trying to configure several horizontal routes (i.e. - not nested) and throw them into one lazy-loaded module.

The thing is, I can't figure out how to match those routes in the lazy-loaded feature module itself.

Here's what the main routing module looks like -

```
      {
        path: 'search/:query',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/archives.module').then(m => m.ArchivesModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'category/:category',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/archives.module').then(m => m.ArchivesModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'tag/:tag',
        loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/archives.module').then(m => m.ArchivesModule),
      },
```

Then, inside my feature module, I'm trying to match those routes based on the path but it's not working -

```
      {
        path: 'search/:query',
        component: SearchComponent,
        resolver: SearchResolver,
      },
      {
        path: 'category/:category',
        component: CategoryComponent,
        resolver: CategoryResolver,
      },
      {
        path: 'tag/:tag',
        component: TagComponent,
        resolver: TagResolver,
      },
```

It does work when I try to access the duplicated routes in full, for example:

```
domain.com/category/:cat/category/:cat
```

So I guess the only thing missing is a way to match parent routes in the feature module, but I couldn't find anything around it.

Comment: can you explain your use case more here ?

Comment: Please add your expected behavior and the expected URL that you want to succeed

Comment: The main reason behind it is to lazyload those routes and components via the same module. Expected behavior is that it'd work under one module, with different paths to that same module.

Comment: @tlt2w one option is you can use only one parent route path `achives` and lazy load it with achive-module. then inside achive-module you can use `category/:category` and so on.. so final route path will be like this `achives/category/`` or `achives/search/1` etc.. so this way you can have your new route structure. see this demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwhd2m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Yeah obviously that's a workaround, but it does not answer my question. I'm mainly trying to understand if it's possible to have different paths/routes leading to the same module.

Comment: As per me answer is No.

Answer (score -1):

The code structure is not clean.
You are making a module that routes to another module using three routes.
Why not removing the routes from the parent module, and just make them in the feature module.
Parent Module:

```
{
    path: '/',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/pages/archives.module').then(m => m.ArchivesModule),
  }
```

Feature Module:

```
{
    path: 'search/:query',
    component: SearchComponent,
    resolver: SearchResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:category',
    component: CategoryComponent,
    resolver: CategoryResolver,
  },
  {
    path: 'tag/:tag',
    component: TagComponent,
    resolver: TagResolver,
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Basically there are a bunch of other routes and paths configured, including the root one ('/'). Those lead to either other lazyloaded modules or regular components. That's why I'm trying to send those completely different routes into the same module (rather than creating 3 separate modules)